# How to get scheme working in emacs

Tags: emacs, scheme

I want to learn scheme using 'Teach yourself scheme in fixnum days' in order to customize reports generated by GnuCash. I am using a windows computer. When I type M-X run-scheme in emacs the response I get is 'Searching for program: permission denied, scheme'. I have done some googling and found that I should put some info in a .emacs file (I am pretty sure this does not exist yet) at location: C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Roaming. The instruction was to add some lines including (setq scheme-program-name "scm") where "scm" is replaced by the name of the scheme interpreter in my installation of emacs.

I have not been able to find the name of my scheme interpreter and also I am very unsure about the whole procedure being new to emacs and scheme. Any specific and / or general guidance here would be very much appreciated, Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You computer probably does not come with a Scheme program; thus, you'll need to install one.  Do a Web Search; plenty of Scheme implementations for Windows.  Once you install it just use it outside of Emacs.  That is, take it step by step - get some familiarity with Scheme, then get some experience with Emacs, then combine the two.

Answer (score 1):

Ooh, let me add to that; I believe that Gnucash uses Guile, the GNU scheme implementation. That's the one you're probably interested in.

Comment: I have made a start learning scheme with DrRacket after your first answer. Do you think I should try Guile additionally or instead of DrRacket?

Comment: I've often thought that GnuCash should use Racket instead of Guile, but that's a different question. If your principal aim is editing Gnucash reports, you should probably stick with Guile. I think I now see the hidden question here: if DrRacket and Guile are implementations of the same language, why not use the one with the best support and libraries? The answer is that, in general, R5RS is a minimal core, and there are substantial differences between different Scheme implementations. If you want to edit Guile code, you should probably stick with Guile.